# VBA: Naming a table of data using a Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to use a Macro to name a table of data so that I can use that name to create a Pivot Table later in my Macro.  The number of rows will change every time I use this Macro,so I need to find one that can identify the last row and grab all the data in Columns A,B,C and D from row 4 down to the last row of data.  My code is presented below, I'm getting an error message on the last line.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Sub Macro22()

Dim Lastrow As Long

Sheets("Statement").Select
Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="VendorData", RefersToR1C1:= _
    "=Statement!A5:C" & Lastrow
ActiveWorkbook.Names("VendorData").Comment = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Names("VendorData").Comment = ""` - that is where you get the error? If so delete the line. It does nothing.

Comment: Yes, that is where I get the message.  How would the name of the table be generated if I remove that line?

Comment: The line above generates the named range `VendorData`. The line below is not even valid syntax.

Comment: I don't know why the recorder would create that syntax when naming a field (which is how I got it).  Even after removing the line, I'm still receiving an error message.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: There is no error message (pardon me), but no name generates for the field.  I think my syntax may be wrong here RefersToR1C1:= _
    "=Statement!A5:C" & Lastrow

Comment: Yes. You are using `R1C1` notation reference without actually using the notation in the formula. Use this instead: `RefersTo:="=Statement!$A$5:$C$ & LastRow`. `$` are used to hold the absolute reference, which is what you want.

Comment: With the $ sign there I get run-time error 1004 on that line

Comment: sorry, this is it: `RefersTo:="=Statement!$A$5:$C$" & LastRow` forgot last `"`

Comment: No problem at all.  I already had that quotation and it still did not work.  This is my current code that the error message was received for:   ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="VendorData", RefersToR1C1:= _
        "=Statement!$A$5:$C$" & Lastrow

Comment: It does not work because you **did not** follow my instructions fully. Change `RefersToR1C1` to `RefersTo`

Comment: Hey thanks man, I really appreciate it. The code works perfectly now

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to set the comment to "" or to remove the comment? Please include the error message you receive next time.

To remove:

```
If Not (ActiveWorkbook.Names("VendorData").Comment is Nothing) then ActiveWorkbook.Names("VendorData").Delete
```

To add/modify the text of a comment:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names("VendorData").Comment.Text ""
```

Comment: I'm getting the error message "Type Mismatch" on Comment when trying to run your code